# HTTP/HTML: Resolution of double dots (..) in the URI (request, Location header etc.)

Tags: http, uri

Are HTTP requests URIs allowed to contain ".." segments?

According to RFC 2616, section 5.1.2, they can refer to absolute URIs or absolute paths (the other options in that section are not relevant for this question).

The meaning of absolute URIs and absolute paths is described in RFC 3986, which also describes an algorithm to normalize paths (that includes remove single and double dot elements).

However, I can't find the exact specification whether an RFC conforming request URI can contain ".." segments - are they allowed in an absolute path/URI, and does the server have to normalize such URIs? Or is that up to the client?

Is there any difference for "Location:" response headers? According to the spec, they can only contain absolute URIs, but does that include ".." parts? Will the client have to normalize those too before requesting the referred resource?

To clarify, I know that URIs like `../foo` are illegal in those situations, but what about `http://example.com/../foo`? Is that a valid absolute URI?

I'm currently redirecting clients to such URIs and would like to know if that is conforming to the specifications.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to *"know if that is conforming to the specifications,"* why don't you simply refer to the relevant specification?

[**RFC 3986 Section 5.2**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2) is very clear on how URI dot segments should be resolved:

> This section describes an algorithm for converting a URI reference
> that might be relative to a given base URI into the parsed components
> of the reference's target.  The components can then be recomposed, as
> described in Section 5.3, to form the target URI.  This algorithm
> provides definitive results that can be used to test the output of
> other implementations.  Applications may implement relative reference
> resolution by using some other algorithm, provided that the results
> match what would be given by this one.

If you are, for example, following `Location:` headers, it's usually prudent to normalize and resolve invalid relative paths (`Location:` headers are supposed to be absolute URIs). In these cases you should absolutely follow the instruction of RFC 3986 to resolve those paths against your base URI.

Should you pass around dot segments in your URIs all over the place? Probably not if you can help it because you're relying on other people to have implemented the specification correctly. But does passing URIs with dot segments violate the URI specification? **No**.

Answer (score 2):

Syntactically speaking, `http://example.com/../foo` is a valid URI.

How the server interprets that URI is a different matter.  Servers have to be very careful about how then translate URIs to file paths, for obvious security reasons.  Usually the server will either strip out `..` segments, or do some kind of post-processing to make sure the file path is inside the document root.

Answer (score 0):

*(Thank you for the great, crisp question in a topic full of hopeless public confusion, fueled by cryptic specs and surprising subtleties!)*

> ... what about http://example.com/../foo? Is that a valid absolute URI?

1. No. It's an *invalid* absolute URI, because it attempts to refer to a place beyond the naming authority's namespace (root).

*(Accordingly, I've been rewarded with due "400 Bad request" responses by servers when trying to feed them stuff like that.)*

2. But, assuming you really meant to ask about *valid*, but equally *non-normalized absolute* paths like `/root/../foo`: @rdlowrey's answer is correct: better normalize them out yourself, if you can.

*(Again, as an example, my proxy failed on pages that worked fine when sent to the same server by browsers, which go the extra mile normalizing the dot-parts out, instead of relying on servers doing the same.)*

> However, I can't find the exact specification whether an RFC
> conforming request URI can contain ".." segments - are they allowed in
> an absolute path/URI, and does the server have to normalize such URIs?
> Or is that up to the client?

3. Unfortunately, you didn't find it because it's not specified, even in [HTTP 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540), AFAICT :-/

Comment: BTW, the example URI is still "valid" syntactically, though, but I had my "semantic" hat on when answering -- I guess because that's the same hat the main control logic of a server wears, too. ;)